# Deciphering Python word unscrambler

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to dig deep into python and I have found a challenge on (hackthissite.org) that I'm trying to crack. I have to unscramble 10 words that are found in the provided wordlist.

```
def permutation(s):
    if s == "":
        return [s]
    else:
        ans = []
        for an in permutation(s[1:]):
            for pos in range(len(an)+1):
                ans.append(an[:pos]+s[0]+an[pos:])
        return ans

def dictionary(wordlist):
    dict = {}
    infile = open(wordlist, "r")
    for line in infile:
        word = line.split("\n")[0]
        # all words in lower case!!!
        word = word.lower()
        dict[word] = 1
    infile.close()
    return dict

def main():
    diction = dictionary("wordlist.txt")
    # enter all the words that fit on a line or limit the number
    anagram = raw_input("Please enter space separated words you need to unscramble: ")
    wordLst = anagram.split(None)

    for word in wordLst:
        anaLst = permutation(word)
        for ana in anaLst:
            if diction.has_key(ana):
                diction[ana] = word
                #print "The solution to the jumble is" , ana
    solutionLst = []
    for k, v in diction.iteritems():
        if v != 1:
            solutionLst.append(k)
            print "%s unscrambled = %s" % (v, k)
    print solutionLst

main()
```

The function permutation looks like it is the block of code that actually does the deciphering. Can you help me understand how it programatically is solving this?

Comment: your indentations are broken.

Comment: Yeah, it was kinda tough to get the python to paste correctly.

Comment: if you identified `permutation` function as one doing the actual job, can't you run it alone and see what it returns?

Comment: Which part or parts do you not understand?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose. I just didn't understand what was going on in between the for loops, really. I see it's creating a blank list at the top by stating ans = [], then I get lost. Where is an declared? "for an in permutation" what is an standing for? I believe what is happening is that it takes the length of the word and matches a character up with it. Am I correct?

Comment: When I was learning programming, I found the concept you are struggling with, pretty hard too. 'an' is just a temporary variable or reference point used in for loops. For instance, one could say something like: people = ["Dom", "James", "Bob"] and then use a for loop: for name in people: do something. 'name' doesn't exist anywhere but inside that for loop. You could call 'name' 'x', 'y' or 'an' as they have in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pseudocode for that looks something like:

```
Load the word list (dictionary)
Input the words to unscramble
For each word:
  Find every permutation of letters in that word (permutation)
  For each permutation:
    Add this permutation to the solution list if it exists in the dictionary
Print the solutions that were found.
```

The dictionary() function is populating your word list from a file.

The permutation() function returns every permutation of letters in a given word.

---

The permutation() function is doing the following:

```
for an in permutation(s[1:]):
```

s[1:] returns the string with the first character truncated. You'll see that it uses recursion to call permutation() again until there are no characters left to be truncated from the front. You must know recursion to understand this line. Using recursion allows this algorithm to cover every number of letters and still be elegant.

```
for pos in range(len(an)+1):
```

For each letter position remaining.

```
ans.append(an[:pos]+s[0]+an[pos:])
```

Generate the permutation by moving the first letter (which we truncated earlier) to each of the positions between every other letter.

---

So, take the word "watch" for example. After recursion, there will be a loop that generates the following words:

awtch
atwch
atcwh
atchw

All I did to generate those words was take the first letter and shift its position. Continue that, combined with truncating the letters, and you'll create every permutation.

(wow, this must be my longest answer yet)

Comment: I added an update that explains the permutation() function in more detail. I hope that clears it up even more :D

Comment: Thank you very much, you have helped my understanding greatly. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There is a much better solution. This code is highly inefficient if there are many long words. A better idea is to sort lexicographically all each word in the dictionary, so that 'god' becomes 'dgo' and do the same for scrambled word. Then it's O(nlogn) for each word instead of O(n!)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code for that site too.
working code below:

```
def import_dictionary():
    dictionary = []
    try:
        file = open("C:\\Users\\Mason\\Desktop\\diction.txt", "r")#location of your dictionary or provided wordlist
        fileContents = file.readlines() #read text file and store each new line as a string
    finally:
        file.close()
    for i in range(len(fileContents)):
        dictionary.extend(fileContents[i].split()) #changes the list by removing \n's from line breaks in text file
    return dictionary

def import_scrambled_words():
    scrambledWords = []
    try:
        file = open("C:\\Users\\Mason\\Desktop\\scrambled.txt", "r") #location of your scrambled word file
        fileContents = file.readlines() #read text file and store each new line as a string
    finally:
        file.close()
    for i in range(len(fileContents)):
        scrambledWords.extend(fileContents[i].split()) #changes the list by removing \n's from line breaks in text file
    return scrambledWords

def unscramble_word(scrambledWord):
    countToMatch = len(scrambledWord)
    matchedWords = []
    string = ""

    for word in dictionary:
        count = 0
        for x in scrambledWord:
            if x in word:
                count += 1
            if count == countToMatch:
                matchedWords.append(word)
                break
    for matchedWord in matchedWords:
        if len(matchedWord) == len(scrambledWord):
            print(matchedWord)
            string = matchedWord
            break #this returns only one unscrambles word
    return string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    finalString = ""
    try:
        scrambled = import_scrambled_words()
        print(scrambled)
        dictionary = import_dictionary()
        for x in scrambled:
            finalString += unscramble_word(x)
            finalString +=", "
        len(finalString)

        print(finalString)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This code will read from a saved file of scrambled words and check it against a wordlist (I used a dictionary in my  case just to be extra). To beat the challenge in the alloted 30 seconds I copy pasted from hackThissite and pasted to my scrambled word file. saved. ran the program and copy pasted the output from my python console.